# Сортировка данных mysql (order by)

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу вывести данный из такой таблицы в нужном порядке?
Таблица:

```
id|favorite|
1 |   0    |
2 |   0    |
3 |   1    |
4 |   0    |
5 |   0    |
```

Вывести строки нужно в таком порядке:

```
id|favorite|
3 |   1    |
5 |   0    |
4 |   0    |
2 |   0    |
1 |   0    |
```

Comment: *Вывести строки нужно в таком порядке:* Правило сортировки надо описывать словами и строго. Например "сначала записи с `favorite=1` в порядке убывания `id`, потом все остальные в порядке убывания `id`". Без такого описания можно наворотить кучу вариантов, которые будут давать требуемый результат на показанных данных и хрень - на других данных.

Comment: @Akina я предоставил как нужно вывести строки

Comment: `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '3,5,4,2,1')` даст строго показанный результат на показанных данных. Используйте. И удачи...

Comment: @Akina а ничего что еще есть столбец `favorite` и он находиться сверху, логично думаю что сортировка происходить по столбцу `favorite`

Comment: Да пофиг. Результат соответствует эталону? соответствует. Других ограничений нет? нет. Всё, задача решена.

Comment: Вот [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2202335a386743133dff463bdc99d0f5).

Answer (score 0):

У вас в вопросе находится ответ.

```
SELECT * FORM table ORDER BY favorite DESC
```

Comment: Добавь ещё уровень сортировки `id DESC`.

Comment: Нет. id тоже должен быть отсортирован desc